# SQLite3 with C++ retrieve ID and store to another table

Tags: c++, sqlite

Good evening people,
I am building a database using SQLite3 and C++ and I want to insert into table "Subs" as a foreign key, the ID which is the primary key for table "Programs". The table Programs has two columns, *Id* and *programCode*. I have the programCode in a variable so my approach is to get the *Id* from the *programCode*, store it into a variable and then store this in the table *Subs*. My problem is that I don't know how to get the result from query and store it into a variable. This is my code:

```
sqlite3_stmt *sql;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT Id FROM Programs WHERE  programCode=?", -1, &sql, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text(sql, 1, _program.c_str(), -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
int step = sqlite3_step(sql);

if(step == SQLITE_ROW) {
   printf("%d\n", sqlite3_column_int(sql, 0));
}
```

The *_program* variable holds the programCode value.
Printf prints nothing and I expected to see the result of the query so I can use this  to store it into  an integer.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the error handling? Anyway, there is no matching row.

Comment: Yes I didn't include the error handling. But you assume the code is correct and there is no matching row to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CL for giving me this piece of information. I checked my csv where I retrieve the information for the database and the *programCode* had a "space" before the text so that is why there was no matching row. Thanks @CL!